# How can I reverse-map (hash) `pthread_t`s to structure pointers?

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable, pthreads

I have a `thread` datatype in the interpreter implementation for a programming language I am working on. For various reasons, it’s a fairly common operation, to need to get the *current* `thread` (which is, itself, a pointer: a `struct thread*`).

However, `pthread_self(3)` hands me a `pthread_t`, which is an opaque type; on some systems, it seems to be an `unsigned long`, but I hear I can’t depend on that being the case. I suspect a hash table is the proper implementation of this unique mapping (`pthread_t` ID to `struct thread` pointer); however, I have no idea how to *hash* the `pthread_t` reliably.

I would appreciate advice from anybody with more experience with `pthread(3)` or, really, any situation wherein you have to “hash” an opaque datatype.

Comment: If it's an opaque type you really can't hash it, since you don't know how big it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to hold your `struct thread*` is thread-local storage.  Something like:

```
static pthread_key_t struct_thread_key;
pthread_key_create(&struct_thread_key, NULL);
```

In the thread initalizer:

```
struct thread *my_thread = malloc(sizeof(*my_thread));
// ...
pthread_setspecific(struct_thread_key, my_thread);
```

To access the current thread later:

```
struct thread *my_thread = (struct thread *) pthread_getspecific(struct_thread_key);
```

Comment: I’m not familiar with local storage, but that might be problematic: the `thread` has to be accessible from, well, other threads of execution: it’s a first-class datatype, that can be passed around freely. It’s only getting the `thread` for the *currently executing* thread of execution, as one of those first-class references, that is problematic…

Comment: @elliott, after you call `getspecific`, you can pass `my_thread` around.  You still may need to do synchronization, of course.

Comment: @elliottcable: That should be fine, since in this example it is the *pointer* to the `struct thread` that is thread-local; the `struct thread` itself is allocated with `malloc()`, so it is global.

Comment: Ah, I commented before seeing your edits; you’re talking about storing *a pointer* to shared memory, in the thread-specific memory for every thread, which stores a reference to that thread’s thread-struct datatype. Perfect! I never considered a solution which didn’t employ `pthread_self(3)` somehow, that’s genius. Thanks! :D

Comment: Hm. `pthread_setspecific(3)` takes a `const void*` as its second argument; are you sure I want to be passing `struct thread*` into it? Should I be be passing `&my_thread` instead? I’m not sure why it takes a pointer, or whether that pointer’s contents are stored, or what; the manpage is a bit unclear on the topic…

Comment: Yes, you can pass `struct thread *`.  You *could* pass `&my_thread` (a `struct thread **`), since *all* pointers are convertible to and from `void *`.  However, I see no reason.  pthread shouldn't dereference the pointer internally, just pass it around.